# Consistency of ADL/ARDL/ARIMAX coefficients

Tags: bias, consistency, ardl

Enders in Applied Econometric Time Series (4th edition, p.282) has following statement about consistency of coefficients in ARDL models:

"For the coefficients of C(L) to be unbiased estimates of the impact effects of {zt} on the {yt} sequence, zt must be uncorrelated with {t} at all leads and lags."

To clarify this statement, the model is this:

yt = a0 + A(L)yt−1 + C(L)zt + t

and hence yt is our dependent variable and zt our exogenous variable.

It is obvious that concurrent correlation would cause bias. However, I canont figure out analytically why zt being correlated with leads or lags of t (i.e. not not concurrently) would on its own cause bias. Moreover, some simulation exercises seem to suggest no problems with consistency. Is it possible he means any leads or lags included in actual equation (i.e. if zt-1 is included, ztmust not be correlated with t-1)?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score -1):

Hi: You can think of it like this or atleast this is how I think of it. Clearly,  all past values of $\epsilon_t$ are contained in the current $y_t$. Therefore, if $z_t$ is correlated with past values of $\epsilon_t$, then $z_t$ is correlated with the current $y_t$. I hope that helps

Also, someone might say: "well, we want $z_t$ to be correlated with $y_t$ since it's a regressor." Yes, that's true but you want it to be correlated because of itself not because it's correlated with previous values of $\epsilon_t$. The latter will cause the biased estimate of the $z_t$ coefficient.

Clearly this is an informal argument. If you want to get into the gory details of lagged dependent variable models, I would check out these two
references. The topic gets pretty involved and there are of course many more references besides these. Specifically, there are poli-sci LDV type papers by Keele and DeBoef that, in some ways, do a better job than the econometrics texts-papers when explaining them.

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-science-research-and-methods/article/to-lag-or-not-to-lag-reevaluating-the-use-of-lagged-dependent-variables-in-regression-analysis/F0B1870165C3FD4AB5CE69D618DF46FD

https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/examples/time-series-regression-viii-lagged-variables-and-estimator-bias.html

ADDENDUM: Take the very simple case where $z_t$ is just one dimensional and leave out the mean $a_{o}$ since it plays no role in the argument.

Then, we can write $y_t = \rho \times y_{t-1} + \beta \times z_t + \epsilon_t$

This can be re-written as $y_t = \beta \times z_t +  \beta  \times \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \rho^{i} z_{t-i} + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \rho^{i} \epsilon_{t-i} +  \epsilon_t$

Note that the third term contains all past $\epsilon_t$ because I took out the current $\epsilon_t$ and wrote it seperately ( same with $z_t$).  Now, it seems pretty clear to me that, if $z_t$, the current value of $z$ at time $t$, is correlated with the third term ( which is the same as saying that it is correlated with some past value $\epsilon_{t-i}$ where $i$ is non-zero ), then the estimate of $\beta$, namely $\hat\beta$, will be biased because the response, $y_t$, at time $t$, can be attributed to either $ \beta \times z_t$ itself or the the third term ( since they are correlated ). I hope this clarifies what I said earlier, atleast to some degree.

Comment: Hi mlofton, I dont think this is it. Note that the model assumes that the residuals are white noise, chiefly through the presence of lagged dependent variables. In other words, after accounting for lagged dependent variables, the effect of past shocks on current yt is not correlated with zt.

Comment: @CrisisStudent: I can definitely be wrong but I'm not clear on what you're saying. Are you saying that $z_t$ can be correlated with past $\epsilon_t$ and you still get an unbiased estimate ? Definitely the LDV piece makes the question of correlation more complex. There's a paper by Mckinnon or Davidson on testing for autocorrelation in the context of LDV's but I haven't been able to track it down ?  If I find it, I'll send the link. Definitely, if anyone else has comments-insights, feel free to correct me.

Comment: @CrisisStudent: I read the question again and  I'm thinking we're not on the same page. It took the OP's question as: "If $z_t$ is correlated with $\epsilon_t$ at some previous lag besides lag zero, would this cause the estimate  of the coefficient of $z_t$ to be biased". Is that how you took it ? My answer was yes and I tried to explain why.

Comment: @CrisisStudent: I added an addendum in order to clarify my argument.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum, it really helps to follow your argument. However, I think that your conclusion does not follow: if I am not wrong, the 2nd and 3rd terms are exactly equal to equal to $y_{t-1}$, something we control for in the original equation. Correlation with anything in these terms is not a problem the same way correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is not a problem in standard regression.

Comment: @CrisisStudent: The two middle terms are close to $y_{t-1}$ but not quite. I'm not clear on your last statement ? Why is correlation with those terms not a problem ? It's not a problem if they're correlated with $y_t$ but it's a problem if they are correlated with $z_t$.

Comment: @CrisisStudent: We don't have to keep talking about this and definitely feel free to provide your insight ( I learn from talking to people ) but I think of it this way:  When added together, the last two terms in the addendum equation comprise the "error term" in the equation for $y_t$. Now,  if $z_t$, a regressor in the equation, is correlated with that error term, then it violates the standard assumption in regression that says that explanatory variables should not be correlated with the error term. That's the way I think of it. If you don't agree, let me know your reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: @CrisisStudent: There are better explanations out there  but 15.4 in this document still explains it better than I did. http://web.thu.edu.tw/wichuang/www/Financial%20Econometrics/Lectures/CHAPTER%2015.pdf

Comment: @CrisisStudent: Note that the issue of correlation-assumption violations always has to do with whether the explanatory variables (regressors) are correlated with the error term, rather than whether they are correlated with each other. In ADL case, A) the lagged dependent variable ( if there is one ) might be correlated with the error term or B) the other non-lagged dependent variables might be correlated with the error term. In either case, if the answer is yes, then the basic assumption of classical OLS is violated.

Comment: Hi: Whoever put a -1 should look at Peter Kennedy's econometrics text. But  there's nothing wrong with my explanation. The sum of last two terms in   addendum equation comprise the error term at time $t$ which one can think of as $\epsilon^{*}_{t}$. Now,  one standard assumption in OLS that the regressors, in this case the lagged dependent variable, $y_{t-1}$ and the regressor, $z_t$, cannot be correlated with the error term $\epsilon^{*}_t$. If either are correlated, this is a violation of classical OLS assumptions. Therefore, the statement is referring to all leads and lags of $\epsilon_t$.

Comment: Note that, by writing the addendum equation as I did, I eliminated the LDV from the model. . But that doesn't change the argument. I still have an equation with current and lagged versions of $z_t$ along with an error term, $\epsilon^{*}_t$.So, if $z_t$ is correlated with $\epsilon^{*}_{t}$, then it's correlated with lags of $\epsilon_{t}$ which means that the original statement   does refer to lags of $\epsilon_t$.  So, my point is that eliminating the lagged dependent variable doesn't change the fact that you still have the same violation if $z_t$ is correlated with lags of $\epsilon_t$.

Comment: Finally, you can estimate this type of model by building the likelihood directly so although there   the violation exists, there's no need to run a regression anyway. So, estimation is no longer the problem that it was back when this model was first developed in the 50's. The simplified one dimensional addendum version is called the koyck distributed lag. Note that Harvey's " The Econometric Analysis of Time Series" is another really nice reference covering this material. It's terse but an amazing book that you come to like more over time than initially.